# Need to get date to what the date picker choose

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need your expertise. How can I show up a specific date in a table base on what date range picker select?

Sample: `7-9-2017 - 7-23-2017`
output should be: `|Sun 9 2017| Mon 10 2017| Tuesday 11 2017| and soon..`

Please i need your help guys.. Thank you in advance. `Jquery` or `Javascript` should be fine

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to this to get from start date to end date using this way

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
console.log(diffDays);
```